# How can I control a EditText in Android to don't enter the same number twice?

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher, charsequence

I tried with Using TextChangedListener, beforeTextChanged and afterTextChanged! but I had no result

Comment: So you want to make it so you cannot enter, for example, 9 twice?

Comment: ItzHoudini yes exactly

Comment: textwatcher is the right approach. Can you share your code?

Answer (score 1):

`TextWatcher` class can help you:

```
   @Override
      public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      }
      @Override
      public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
          int arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      }
      @Override
      public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int a, int b, int c) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        output.setText(s);
        if(a == 9){
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Maximum Limit Reached", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
      }};
```

[Complete reference could be found here](http://www.learn2crack.com/2014/02/android-textwatcher-example.html).

Answer (score 0):

this work for me :)

```
txtwt = new TextWatcher()
    {
       char last ;
       @Override
       public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
       {
           if (s.toString().length() >= 1)
                EntredNumber = s.toString();
        }
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
        {
            if (s.toString().length() >= 2)
            {
                last = (s.toString().charAt(s.toString().length() - 1));
               // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), last +"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (EntredNumber.contains((last + "")))
                {
                    txtImputNumber.removeTextChangedListener(txtwt);
                    txtImputNumber.setText(EntredNumber);
                    txtImputNumber.setSelection(EntredNumber.length());
                    txtImputNumber.addTextChangedListener(txtwt);
                }
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
        {
        }
    };

   txtImputNumber.addTextChangedListener(txtwt);
```